# ¿Qué hace la función genqammod en MatLab?

Tags: matlab

Les quiero hacer la siguiente pregunta. Encontré el siguiente ejemplo en la página de MatLab, lo cuál no logro comprender lo que hace la función `genqammod` y como se define el vector `x = []`. No entiendo que valores tengo que usar. Les dejo el siguiente link del ejemplo

Ejemplo: https://la.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/genqammod.html.

Comment: Hola Francisca, he respondido al uso de la función genqammod y a la forma de definir un vector. Sin embargo, no he podido acceder al ejemplo en cuestión dado que, no se encontraba disponible. Por esa razón es conveniente incluir en la pregunta las partes principales del ejemplo para que, en caso de que no se encuentre disponible, futuros usuarios puedan tener una referencia. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `genqammod` o su nomenclatura original **General quadrature amplitude modulation (QAM)** es una función que permite la **modulación de amplitud en cuadratura**.

La modulación de amplitud en cuadratura es una técnica que transporta dos señales independientes, mediante la modulación o desplazamiento, tanto en amplitud como en fase, dos señales portadoras con la misma frecuencia pero que desfasadas entre sí 90°. La señal modulada en QAM está compuesta por la suma lineal de las dos señales previamente moduladas.

**Usos**

Como actual estudiante he usado esta función en contadas ocasiones para temas relacionados con Física, en especial para **Teoría de Circuitos**. **De forma muy general y simplificada**, si entrar en temas de Física este tipo de modulación sirve para **favorecer el aprovechamiento del ancho de banda disponible**

**Sintaxis**

```
y = genqammod(x, const)
```

Respecto a la forma de definir un vector es necesario realizar una clara diferenciación. **Un vector no es lo mismo que una matriz, por ende, la forma de definirlos no son iguales.**

Para definir un vector, hacemos uso de la función `colon,:`

**Sintaxis**

```
x = j:k
```

donde `x = j:k` crea un vector `x` de espaciado **unitario** con elementos `j` de la forma `[j,j+1,j+2,...,j+n]`

En MatLab para definir una matriz se realiza de la siguiente forma (Similar a la creación de un array)

```
a = [1 2 3 4]

Output: 1     2     3     4
```

La matriz `a` por tanto, tendrá dimensión `1x4`  →  `a = 1x4` y será una **matriz fila**

Si queremos definir una matriz con varias filas, la forma de definir dicha matriz es:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 10]
```

donde la matriz tendrá dimensión `a = 3×3`

```
Output:

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8    10
```

Por último, si queremos definir una **matriz fila** o una **matriz columna** cuyas componentes seán todos 0 podemos definir la matriz haciendo uso de la función `zeros` de la siguiente forma:

```
z = zeros(5,1)
```

donde los valores `(5,1)` indican la **dimensión de la matriz**. En este caso, es una **matriz fila** que cuenta con **5 filas** y **1 columna**

**Ejemplo**

```
z = zeros(5,1)

z = 5×1

     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```